# Accessing My Content Provider From Another App

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

when you are trying to access a content provider from a separate application does that app have to be running to access its cp?

Lastly how do I query from a separate content provider. The only example I found used managedQuery which is deprecated.

Any Examples or walk throughs would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, `ContentProvider`s are first class components (just like activities and services) and can be accessed at any time.
2. The [Content Provider basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) go through the main points of accessing a `ContentProvider` using [getContentResolver().query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) (where `getContentResolver()` is a method from `Context`).

You can also use [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) to provide asynchronous insert/update/delete/query capabilities, which is great for one off queries where you don't want to tie up the main thread (as long queries could make your app appear unresponsive).

However, for reoccuring queries, the [Loader framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) (also available via the Support Library) and [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) are by far the easiest way to work with `ContentProvider`s as they will automatically refresh data as it changes (assuming your `ContentProvider` is calling [notifyChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) on the appropriate URIs after each operation).